# Why can't my program set 0777 mode with the mkdir system call?

Tags: c, linux

I wrote following code to try to create a directory with 0777 mode on Linux:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main () {

    mkdir("/tmp/mkdir-test", 0777);
    return 0;

}
```

But actually, the new directory has 0755 mode.

```
# stat /tmp/mkdir-test
  File: `/tmp/mkdir-test'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 1772304     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2016-09-27 20:23:54.000000000 -0700
Modify: 2016-09-27 20:23:54.000000000 -0700
Change: 2016-09-27 20:23:54.000000000 -0700
```

Can someone explain this? And how can the program create a real 0777 mode directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run [`umask`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/umask.html) in the shell; it will report `022`.  The bits set in the `umask` value are removed from permissions when creating files or directories.

In a single-threaded program, one way to really set `0777` permissions is to dink with [`umask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html):

```
mode_t old_mask = umask(0);
mkdir("/tmp/mkdir-test", 0777);
umask(old_mask);
```

That preserves the current setting except when you are sure you need to override it.  However, this is dangerous in multi-threaded programs because the `umask` value is global per-process, not per-thread (and thanks to [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39737609/why-cant-my-program-set-0777-mode-with-the-mkdir-system-call/39737630?noredirect=1#comment110495511_39737630)).

The other option for setting the permissions is to use `chmod()`, and doing so is safe with multi-threaded programs too:

```
const char *dirname = "/tmp/mkdir-test";
mode_t target_mode = 0777;
if (mkdir(dirname, 0) == 0)
    chmod(dirname, target_mode);
```

The permissions set by the [`chmod()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html) function are not affected by `umask` values.

The permissions on the call to `mkdir()` are probably best set to `0` as shown;  it will always work reliably and doesn't risk affecting other threads by modifying the `umask` value.  Alternatively, you could use the desired target permissions in the call to `mkdir()` if you wanted to (and a previous version of this answer suggested doing so, using `0777` as the hard-coded target permissions).

```
const char *dirname = "/tmp/mkdir-test";
mode_t target_mode = 0777;
if (mkdir(dirname, target_mode) == 0)
    chmod(dirname, target_mode);
```

If you use this idiom, it is important that the mode passed to `mkdir()` is the same as, or less permissive than, the mode passed to `chmod()` — and `0` is less permissive than any other mode (and always works).
If you use a more relaxed mode in the call to `mkdir()`, there's a TOCTOU (Time-of-Check, Time-of-Use) style vulnerability between the `mkdir()` and `chmod()` calls during which someone (some process) could get into the directory with relaxed permissions and wreak havoc; this could be a security risk.

Note that `umask()` is a very simple system call and therefore very quick too (as system calls go, compared with heavyweights such as `open()`, `mkdir()` or `chmod()`).

Comment: And it is even documented, @walker, in the docs for `mkdir(3)`.  For example, the Linux version says "The file permission bits of the new directory shall be initialized from `mode`. **These file permission bits of the `mode` argument shall be modified by the process' file creation mask**"  (emphasis added).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I just tried to call chmod after mkdir to solve the issue. it also works. My question is what's the different between two ways? Which way is more recommended?

Comment: I think `umask()`, `mkdir()`, `umask()` is probably better, unless you need to set the `S_ISVTX` (sticky bit)  or the `S_ISGUID` bit on the directory.  For those, on macOS Sierra (and Mac OS X before it), you need to use `chmod()` because `mkdir(2)` says: _Note: the behavior of mkdir() is undefined when mode bits other than the low 9 bits are used. Use chmod(2) after mkdir() to explicitly set the other bits._. So, if you need to call `chmod()` anyway, use `mkdir()` plus `chmod()` — otherwise use `umask()`, `mkdir()`, `umask()`.

Comment: Yes, wherever possible, it is best to create files / directories with the intended mode from the beginning, instead of changing the mode after creation.  Additionally, if you need to create multiple directories and / or files, then modifying the umask once for all (and maybe restoring it later) saves you from performing a `chmod()` on each.

Comment: Contrary opinion: [File Permission Problems In Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12391417) - umask is global, not per thread; treat it as a user configuration that you don't mess with.  You can always start with very restricted permissions and relax them with `chmod`.  Unless I'm mistaken, a `umask` setting can't give more permissions that `mkdir()` specified so the TOCTOU-like vulnerability is impossible.

Comment: @PeterCordes — thread-safety is an important point; thank you.  I've revised the answer to account for that.  Using 0 for the mode in the call to `mkdir()` and then using `chmod()` should always be safe.  No `umask` setting adds bits to the value specified in `mkdir()` or any other 'create file' operation; it can only remove bits.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the permission wasn't set to 0777.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa — without seeing your code and knowing your `umask` value and knowing what you _do_ get as the result, it is not possible to help you.  It may be best to ask a new question cross-referencing this one.  Don't forget to check the return value from system calls.

Comment: I resolved it already. I'll post my solution as an answer so that it can help anyone  else coming across this later